# How do I restart a failed JSR-352 job running in Liberty through Eclipse / WDT?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, jsr352

While running the Java EE Batch job through eclipse, it is creating a new instance of it.

I wanted to re-run the failed instance so that it can use checkpoint information to resume from the failed point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Deploy Application into Liberty server.
   Step 2: Run the batchManger.bat file from cmd, which can find under bin folder of your local server

```
.\batchManager.bat restart --batchManager=localhost:9443 --user=admin --password=P@ssw0rd --applicationName=your-app-Name --jobXMLName=XXXX.xml --wait --trustSslCertificates
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (GUI) approach is to use the [Admin Center Java Batch tool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_ui_jb_using.html), which allows you to restart jobs submitted by other methods.  You can reuse, and/or modify the original job execution parameters.

This also provides a rich set of search and filtering capabilities, plus lets you view job logs, and so complements the job submission capability in the Eclipse Java EE Batch tooling.

Start [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_ui.html) for complete instructions on using Admin Center.  In particular you need to make sure the `adminCenter-1.0` feature is installed then [configure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_ui_setup.html#twlp_ui_setup__uiconfserv) a userid to be authorized as the administrator.

Then, as the Java Batch tool [instructions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_ui_jb_using.html) say, configure your server.xml with features:

```
adminCenter-1.0
batchManagement-1.0
```

Comment: I am getting error while accessing the admincenter      `                                                                        [ERROR   ] CWWKO0801E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired. Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)`

Comment: Your problem is likely to be a general issue making a secure connection (over HTTPS) into the server, and not an issue with the admincenter or the batch management function specifically.  Your best bet is to search for support for this issue (e.g. this CWWKO0801E message) from a broad, general perspective.